# Check or validate html tags in php

Tags: php, html

I rally tried a lot. I have googled, but I still cannot figure out how to solve this problem. That is, I'm having the same output 'this document is invalid' for both inputs and a warning. This is my code:

```
$correct_structure = ['<a>', '<div>', '</div>', '</a>', '<span>', '</span>'];

$incorrect_structure = ['<a>', '<div>', '</a>', '<p>' , '</tr>'];

function validate_html_tags($html_tags) {

$tags = htmlspecialchars(implode("", $html_tags));
$html_doc="<!DOCTYPE html>" . "<html><body>" . $tags . "</body></html>";    
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_doc);
$dom->saveHTML();

if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
} else {
    echo "This document is invalid!\n";
}

return $tags;
```

}

```
The Warnings: 
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): No declaration for element html
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): No declaration for element body in 
This document is invalid!
```

Comment: I need to return valid html tags.Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please add the expected output of your function.

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of to do this is using `DOMDocument`. Concatenate your array into a string, add some necessary stuff like a Doctype, then use `DOMDocument::validate`, as in this manual page:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php

For example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_string);
if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
}
```

Comment: Ynhockey, thanks the answer. But I am still getting some warnings when I call $dom->validate():DOMDocument::validate(http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  DOMDocument::validate(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd" DOMDocument::validate(): Could not load the external subset "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"

Comment: Maybe it has to do with `allow_url_fopen`, or maybe you didn't add a valid doctype? Try checking both these directions.

Comment: I think the suggestion is in the error :) it says you don't have html and body tags, which are required in HTML 4. Also: please don't radically alter the question after there is an existing answer. You can always ask another question if it's a separate issue (even if related).